# Returning values into GlobalScope launch using Spring

Tags: spring, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an endpoint exposed, that is launching a coroutine:

```
val apiCall = ApiCall()

@GetMapping("/example")
fun example(@RequestParam paramExample:String):Int{
    GlobalScope.launch{
        return apiCall.callApi(paramExample)
    }
}
```

This function is calling another external API, using Retrofit:

```
suspend fun callApi(param:String):Int{
    var tot_records =0
    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(appProperties.sampleUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    val service = retrofit.create<ResponseService>(ResponseService::class.java)

    service.getResponse().enqueue(object : Callback<Response> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Response>, throwable: Throwable) {
            println("Error")
            println(throwable.stackTrace)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Response>, response: Response<Response>) {
            println("OK")
            println(response.body())
            println("Tot records")
            tot_records = response.body()?.tot_records!!
        }
    })
    return tot_records
}
```

The problem is that I can't launch this, the error is: 'return' is not allowed here

Any idea how to fix it and whats is happening?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you can't decide if you want your code to be synchronous (so code waits for its subtasks to finish before continuing) or asynchronous (it launches operations in the background). You intend to return a result from `example()`, so you need it to be synchronous, but you immediately use `launch()` to invoke `callApi()` asynchronously. The same in `callApi()` - you intend to return from it (so synchronous), but you invoke Retrofit using callbacks (so asynchronous). Note that `callApi()` has exactly the same problem as `example()`. Even if it compiles, it still does not really work properly. It always returns `0`, because `tot_records` is returned before being set.

You have to decide between asynchronous and synchronous and stick to it. If you want to go fully asynchronous, then you need to redesign both `callApi()` and `example()` to return their results either with callbacks or futures.

However, I suggest going fully synchronous, utilizing Kotlin suspend functions. Make all functions suspend: `example()`,  `callApi()` (it is already) and `ResponseService.getResponse()`. The last one will look something like:

```kotlin
suspend fun getResponse(): Response
```

Then remove `GlobalScope.launch()`, and almost everything inside `enqueue()`. Instead, `service.getResponse()` will return `Response` object directly, so you can just return its `tot_records` property.

Also note that in your original code you ignored failures. After above change `service.getResponse()` will throw exceptions on failures, so you have to handle them.

Comment: If I turn this to synchronous methods, it will be blocked if many requests are made at the same time right? This is why I was using it inside the launch body. 

I thik I can't remove anything inside the enqueue, this two methods are necessary.

If I remove the GlobalScope.launch and make that suspend fun, it's giving me NoSuchMethodException, whic I read that is a bug that they are fixing

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "blocked". Yes, `example()` will wait for the request to complete, but I guess this is what you expect, because you want to return the result of this request from `example()`. You can't wait for the result and don't wait for it at the same time ;-) If you want to e.g. execute multiple `example()` requests (or other, similar functions) at the same time, then just do: `async { example() }; async { example2() }`. The whole `enqueue()` block is only required when returning `Call<>` from the API. After changing it to suspend, it becomes irrelevant.

Comment: What do you mean by `NoSuchMethodException`? What is the exact error message? Also, it is pretty strange, that you use `Response<Response>` in your original code. Are these two distinct `Response` types: one from Retrofit and one your own?

Comment: but if y put aysnc{} inside my example() function, I can't return any result when calling my callApi function

Comment: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: kotlinx.coroutines.reactor.MonoKt.mono(Lkotlin/coroutines/CoroutineContext;Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function2;)Lreactor/core/publisher/Mono;] with root cause

Comment: Anyways, what I'm trying to do is to call the external API, and return the result without blocking anything in order to manage multiple petitions at the same time, any idea?

Comment: Yes, I understand and this is exactly what you get by making all functions suspendable (or by going fully asynchronous - this is just less convenient to code). Suspend function waits for the result, so it returns it directly and it does not block any thread. What is the exact case that you can't implement with a suspend function? One thing that you can't do is to return the result from non-suspend function invoked from the main thread. This is essentially impossible no matter what you do, because non-suspend functions can't wait in any other way than blocking.

Comment: And regarding your exception: I found similar reports in the internet, but they weren't bugs. They were caused by using multiple coroutines libraries with incompatible versions.

Comment: I think I solved the problem, I will post in another comment to be clear

Answer (score 0):

This solution seems that works:

This is the endpoint declaration:

```
@GetMapping("/example")
suspend fun example(@RequestParam param:String):CustomResponse{
    return coroutineScope {
        val job = async{apiCall.callApi(param)}
        job.await()
    }
}
```

And this is my function that is calling an external API:

```
suspend fun callApi(param:String):CustomResponse{
    var responseCustom = CustomResponse()
    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(appProperties.reservationUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    val service = retrofit.create<CustomResponseService>(CustomResponseService::class.java)

    responseCustom = service.getResponse(appProperties.token, param).execute().body()!!

    return responseCustom
}
```

Comment: Your `example()` could be replaced with just: `apiCall.callApi(param)` - it is the same.

Comment: Also note that `execute()` blocks the thread. You should probably enclose this in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}` to avoid blocking the main thread or other thread that should never be blocked.

Comment: Would be posible for you to explain me what is `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {}` doing? seems a good solution and it would be interesting to know about it. Thanks

Comment: It just switches to the thread that is safe to become blocked. Original thread that invoked `callApi()` is free to do something else until `withContext()` finishes. Anyway, blocking calls are generally not recommended, so replacing `enqueue()` with `execute()` is like a step back. However, if for some reason you can't turn `service.getResponse()` into a suspend function, then I guess `execute()` and `withContext()` is better than nothing.

Comment: Must see how to manage `enqueue()` instead of `execute()`, but thanks anyway, your help was great!